# assignment from an array changes the array itself

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

When assigning a value from an array to another one, the array on the right hand side changes. Could you point me towards the possible mistake that I make?

The code below finds longest increasing sequence and I have the problem with the last line `yy[-1] = y[n]`. Whenever this line executed a value in y also changes.

```
import numpy as np

p = np.array([466, 5500, 2615, 4056, 2196, 4254, 2987, 5125, 1060, 7344, 2990])
y = p.argsort()

yy = y[-2:]
yy = yy[::-1]

n = len(y)-2

while(n>0):
    n = n-1
    if (y[n] < yy[-1]):
        yy = np.append(yy,y[n])

    if ((y[n] > yy[-1]) & (y[n] < yy[-2])):
            yy[-1] = y[n]
```

Comment: I haven't read your code with due attention, but from the top of my head it seems like the problem occurs since NumPy arrays return lightweight wrappers when sliced, not new arrays. Hence `yy` and `y` are different views of the same array. Hence all operations on shared positions effect both `y` and `yy`

Comment: But then you've got `np.append` there, that does return a new array at some point. BTW, using `np.append` in a loop is highly inefficient. If you really need fast lightweight dynamic C-arrays with in-place `append`, use `array.array`. Just convert it to a NumPy array once the loop is over, if you need special NumPy functionality.

Comment: @EliKorvigo Thanks for the comments for improvement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can read in the [numpy guide](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> All arrays generated by basic slicing are always views of the original array.

This means that the `y` and `yy` are basically different views of the same underlying data structure. So when you change the first you are also changing the second one and vice versa.

The easiest thing is to copy the array after slicing it, turning the following line:

```
yy = y[-2:]
```

into:

```
yy = y[-2:].copy()
```